# ¿Cómo tracear las imágenes de un sitio si no puedo cambiar las rutas?

Tags: php, html, jquery, img, tracking

Es una pregunta para la que ya tengo respuesta, pero pensé que le podría ir bien a más de uno y en varios casos. Por supuesto, acepto nuevas respuestas con otros métodos.

Se trata de poder guardar las impresiones de las imágenes en un sitio ya existente en el que no puedo/debo modificar los src de las mismas por ser complejo o extenso, por ejemplo.

El objetivo es guardar un contador en la base de datos de una imagen de un html con la siguiente forma:

```
<img src="img/foto.jpg" alt="foto">
```

Tengo la base de datos con una tabla "images" y con un id autonumérico, la ruta y nombre de la imagen y un contador por defecto establecido a 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya que no se pueden modificar las rutas de las imágenes y poner por ejemplo en el src: track.php?img=foto1.jpg

Se me ocurrió hacerlo de la siguiente manera:

Creo un fichero image.php con el siguiente contenido, en este ejemplo, lo hago solo para imágenes de tipo .jpg:

```
<?php
    include("inc/ddbb.php");
    $img = $db->real_escape_string($_REQUEST["img"]);
    $db->query("UPDATE images SET impresiones = (impresiones + 1) WHERE image = '" . $img . "';");
    header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
    readfile($img);
?>
```

¡Cuidado! ya que he omitido unos pasos básicos de seguridad para hacerlo más simple.

Este fichero, recibirá una variable con la imagen a mostrar y se encargará de guardar en la base de datos, un incremento en el campo impresiones y luego devolverá la imagen.

Ahora se trata de capturar las imágenes y para ello, creo un fichero .htaccess con el siguiente contenido:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule ^img/(.*)$ image.php?img=$1&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
</IfModule>
```

Y listo, ahora cada vez que una imagen es cargada, ya sea en el src, de forma directa o por medio de javascript, la regla del .htaccess se encargará de redirigir a image.php pasando el parámetro img con la imagen a mostrar.

Esto, por supuesto, se puede hacer con cualquier fichero, ya sea un .js, un .html o dentro de una carpeta en concreto.