# ¿como actualizar mi tabla en mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

Estoy realizando un pequeño sistema de base de datos, que guarda archivos, la parte del cliente solo puede descargar los archivos, y la administración puede insertar mas, modificar y descargar, pero cuando el cliente descargue el archivo, a la administración le debe aparecer en su tabla que archivos han sido descargados, esa parte de que se guarde el registro que ya se ha descargado cada archivo es la que no puedo hacer. Este es el código de cuando le doy descargar

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET["id"])){
    include "db.php";
    $img = get_img($_GET["id"]);
    if($img!=null){
        del($img->id);
        $fullpath = $img->folder.$img->src;
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$img->src");
        readfile($fullpath);
    }
}
?>
```

Este es el codigo con el que inserto en la base de datos

```
function con(){
    return new mysqli("localhost","root","","multi_upload");
}

function insert_img($folder, $image){
    $con = con();
    $con->query("insert into image (folder,src,created_at) value (\"$folder\",\"$image\",NOW())");
}
```

Mi idea es poner un cero a cada registro de archivo, y que cuando el cliente le de en descargar, se actualice el registro del archivo y cambie el cero por un uno, y después en la tabla de la administración hacer una consulta, y si el registro tiene un uno ponga descargado, pero no se como hacer esto.
eh aqui el codigo donde el cliente a través del rfc busca sus documentos, y el nombre del documento tiene su rfc, así se me hizo más facil la consulta

Subir Multiples Imagenes y/o Archivos - By Evilnapsis
        


    
    


      
     @media (max-width: 600px) { 
#busc_prov{
  flex-direction: column;
}
#encavezado{
  margin-bottom: 20%;
  display: flex;
  flex: 1 1 0px;
}
#busca_prov{
  display: flex;
  flex: 1 1 0px;
  margin-bottom: 35%;
}
} 
@media (max-width: 415px) { 
#busc_prov{
  flex-direction: column;
}
#encavezado{
  margin-bottom: 30%;
  display: flex;
  flex: 1 1 0px;
}
#busca_prov{
  display: flex;
  flex: 1 1 0px;
  margin-bottom: 45%;
}
}  

    

    
  
    Parque Industrial Querétaro

    
      
    

    
      
      

      
      Inicio
      Intranet
          cerrar sesión

## Archivos

Ingresa tu RFC para acceder a tus Facturas
              
            
                        Ver mis Facturas
                          

             
           

             


        0):?>
        
    
  
            
    

      Nombre
      fecha
      

    
  
            
                

                src;?>
                created_at;?>
                id; ?>">Descargar

                
            
            
             
             
         alert('no hay conincidencias con la busquedad');")?>

```
    <?php endif; ?>
    <footer class="footer text-muted bg-light">
```

© 2019 Parque Industrial Queretaro

Comment: Ok, vamos poco a poco, que tiene buena pinta pero faltan cosas. En primer lugar, utiliza Ctrl+k para el código porque así no se lee muy bien. Después, modifica la pregunta e incorpora la estructura de la tabla en SQL con algún registro para las pruebas (phpMyAdmin,Exportar) y así podamos montar un [Ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  Aquí se explica mucho mejor [ask]. Bienvendo a [so]

Comment: No entiendo bien cuál es el problema. Cuando alguien descarga un archivo el estado de descargado se debe poner en `1` para ese archivo, según la lógica que expones. ¿Estoy en lo cierto? Luego, ¿qué es lo que no funciona? ¿hablamos de un contador de descargas o sólo interesa que se ponga en `1`? ¿Hablamos de relaciones entre descargadores y descargas, o sea, de saber quién descargó qué archivos? Falta claridad en la pregunta y falta decir **lo que no funciona**, qué debería hacer y qué hace actualmente.

Comment: tengo mi tabla archivo, con campo 'id', 'folder', 'src', 'fecha' y 'estado', el campo estado al momento que se hace la inserción se pone en cero, lo que quiero hacer es que cuando el cliente le de en descragar, me actualice el registro del archivo que descragó, para que en la tabla del administrador le aparezca que ya se ha descargado ese archivo

Comment: Te recomiendo cambiar el enfoque de la descarga, si el conteo de las descargas es crucial, es mejor contabilizar desde .htaccess, redirigiendo los ficheros de descarga a un PHP como el que nos muestras, pasando el id del fichero sería más seguro y entonces el PHP debe buscar el fichero y mostrarlo, pero antes lanzar un update en la base de datos. Te recomiendo que veas [mi pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/243515/c%c3%b3mo-tracear-las-im%c3%a1genes-de-un-sitio-si-no-puedo-cambiar-las-rutas) que realizé al uso de .htaccess para esta técnica, deberás adaptarlo, pero te vale.

Comment: el estado no es para contabilizar las descragas, es solo para utilizarlo como referencia, y en la tabla de la administracion hacer una consulta, para verificar si ya tiene un uno es que ya se descrago, de lo contrario no se ha descargado.

Comment: No veo en tu pregunta el código que controla las descargas de los usuarios y lanza la actualización a la tabla.

Comment: ya lo arreglé, muchas gracias